# handle the case of consumer death when each consumer subscribes to a partition in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, partition

My system has 2 services:

- Service A publishes messages via a Kaffka Topic (with 5 partitions, P0, P1, P2, P3, P4 at initialization)
- Service B has 10 instances in total, which are deployed on both on-premise and AWS. Each 2 instances handles messages on 1 partition of Kafka topic
  Instance of service B can't be deployed to K8S as the infrastructure are both On-premise and AWS.

The system seems to be designed well, however, I'm considering these cases and still doesn't have solutions for them:

- What if 2 consumers handling messages for partition P0 break down the same time?
- What needs to be done in service B when we need to increase/decrease the number of partitions?
- What if service B needs to callback some information for service A after implementing business logic?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: How are you assigning the consumers to the consumed partitions? Are you using consumer groups and the default partition assignment?

Comment: I assign manually and don't use consumer groups

Comment: Any reason why you are not using consumer groups? The first two cases would be automatically handled for you (and are a couple of the major reasons why consumers groups exist, automatic scale-up/down and failover). Otherwise, you need to manually handle these cases (detect the number of consumers changed, reassign partitions...). I'm not sure what you mean in case 3 but I don't see how it is related to the kafka consumers

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, in total you would be having 10 consumer instances, distributed and deployed under two consumer groups, and each one having 5 consumer instances.

So for a given point in time, each partition will be assigned to 2 consumers instance, one from each consumer group.

What if 2 consumers handling messages for partition P0 break down the same time?

**Ans:** Re-balance will happen immediately (It depends on other factors such as session, heartbeat timeouts and closing a consumer through Finally()), and the Partition 0 will be assigned to other active consumer instances.

What needs to be done in service B when we need to increase/decrease the number of partitions?

**Ans:** Increasing the partitions is an admin task done on the broker side, and you need not do anything on the Service B, unless, your consumer instances having any Partition Assignor based logic.

What if service B needs to callback some information for service A after implementing business logic?

**Ans:** From your perspective, Service A and Service B are two independent clients integrated via broker. So call-back some information, but be done via broker for Future Java Object or Meta Data handling unless you have exposed any RPC.